# How to integrate apache james into my spring web application

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, integration, james

we are developing a spring mvc web application and we need some internal messaging system, and i come across the apache james, i installed and use the apache james its working perfectly. But i need to integrate this to our application like when start application apache james need to start and when create the user in our application we need to create user in apache james in a specific domain without using those shell scripts/batch . I dont know where to start and how to do. give me some advise and resource related this. please help me. thank you.

Comment: Did you get anything?